# How to generate modules.dep file?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I tried to build a linux module(Hello World)I created a directory(test) created the hello.c file and the Makefile the same directory.After compiling the Makefile,I didn't got any modules.dep file.
Is this an issue?If yes,how do I generate modules.dep file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your module is dependent on another modules run the **depmod** command to update the module dependency files.
See [man depmod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod).